# SwiftUI / Firestore "Cannot convert value of type 'String" to expected argument type ''

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a fitness app and when a user favorites a trainer account on the app I want to fetch all the workouts that that specific trainer has posted and then add it to the user's feed.

**When you favorite a trainer account I fetch all the workouts and write them to an array in Firestore with this function:**

```
func addToUserFeed() {
    guard let trainerUid = trainer.id else { return }
    guard let currentUid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else { return }

    COLLECTION_WORKOUTS.whereField("ownerUid", isEqualTo: trainerUid).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ in
        guard let workoutIDs = snapshot?.documents.map({ $0.documentID }) else { return }
        let docData: [String: Any] = ["workouts": workoutIDs]
        COLLECTION_USERS.document(currentUid).collection("user-feed").document(trainerUid).setData(docData)

    }
}
```

**Then in Firestore it looks like this:**

[Firestore structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HxUr.png)

So it creates a new document in the collection "user-feed" which is the trainer ID of the trainer they just favorited, and then creates an array in that document of all the workout IDs that are associated with that trainer ID.

Then I am trying to create a function in my view model that fetches those workoutIDs in the array on firestore and puts them on the user feed.

**Function to fetch all workouts in those arrays:**

```
func fetchFavoriteWorkouts(){
    
    guard let currentUid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else { return }

    COLLECTION_USERS.document(currentUid).collection("user-feed").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ in
                    
        for document in snapshot!.documents {
            
            let workouts = document.get("workouts") as! [String]
            print("WORKOUTS TESTING: \(workouts)")
            
            for workout in workouts {
                
                //self.workouts.append(workout)
                print("WORKOUTS TESTING: \(workout)")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I uncomment the line "self.workouts.append(workout)" I get the error that I cannot convert type string to the type workout model object I have. Any way I can convert this string type to be of type workout so I can use them to fetch workouts from the ID in firestore?

Comment: you could use: `self.workouts.append(Workout(workout))` and implement the required `init(...)` 
in your `Workout` object model.

Comment: We recommend using Codable to map data - see https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/. I'd also recommend not using force unwrap, as your app will crash if the data can't be mapped.

Answer (score 0):

In my app viewModel i use a structure like this to get my objects for firestore. try it out and adapt it for your, it should work. (You struct Workout should conform to the protocol Codable)

add this in your view model

```
private var db = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchFavoriteWorkout(){    
    guard let currentUid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else { return }
        db.collection("user_feed").document(currentUid)
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Didn't find any document")
                return
            }
            let tempWorkout = documents.compactMap{ (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Workout? in
                try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Workout.self)
            }
            self.workouts = tempWorkout
        }
    }
```